# Работа с фоновым таймером

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Имеем Google расширение которое должно периодически выводить информацию в виде Badge на иконке приложения.
Пользователь должен иметь возможность менять интервал обновления.

Проблема в том что я не могу получить идентификатор запущенного таймера и соответственно не могу остановить таймер чтобы задать новый интервал. В файле options.js переменная `_timerID` - пуста! Я даже пробовал идентификатор таймера записывать в LocalStorage, но таймер не останавливается, видимо он существует в другом "пространстве"...

- Вопрос №1, мне остановить таймер?
- Вопрос №2, как делать подобные вещи    наиболее правильно?

Вот файлы проекта:

В манифесте в качестве background используется `background.html` на котрой подключаются:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bg.js"></script>
```

На страничке `options.html`, которая отображает настройки подключаются:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/options.js"></script>
```

> bg.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (_enableTick)
    startTimer();
});
```

> main.js

```
var _enableTick, _updateTime, _timerID;

function startTimer() {
  _timerID = window.setInterval(function() {
    setBadge(serverID);
  }, _updateTime));
}
```

> options.js

```
function save_options() {
  clearInterval(_timerID);
}
```

Comment: Первым делом скажите - что из этого content-script, что скрипт pop-апа, что в background страничке запускается? Это довольно важно.

Comment: Рекомендую не использовать setInterval, т.к. в определённых условиях он может забить стек

Comment: @ThisMan content-script'ом ничего из этого не является. Файл popup'а зачем он вам? возможно вы имели ввиду `options.js`... Что в `background.html` и в `options.html` инклюдится я указал в вопросе (обновил).

Comment: @SanSYS что рекомендуете? Я не против уйти от него только вот как а вернее чем заменить его?

Comment: @jackrv, рекомендую рассмотреть вот такую возможность http://jsfiddle.net/tygpu2kh/

а в теле самой функции можно вообще написать, что-то вроде if (isEnable) do come work else nothing; set next timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень понравился вариант предложенный @SanSYS поэтому код преобразился в такой
(Единственное что меня смущает, постоянное чтение параметров с storage..)

> main.js

```
function startTimer() {
(function timer(){
  if (localStorage["setting:enableTick"]) {
    getServerInfo(function() {
      setBadge('bla-bla');
    });
  } else setBadge();
    clearTimeout(timer.id);
    var interval = parseInt(localStorage["setting:updateTime"]); 
    timer.id = setTimeout(timer, interval * 1000);
  })();
}
```

> options.js

```
localStorage["setting:enableTick"] = $('#enableBadge').prop("checked");
localStorage["setting:updateTime"] = $('#timeUpdate').val();

startTimer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте либо создать объект, а внутри него уже сделать эти методы по запуску таймера и хранить ид таймера внутри объекта

либо вот такой изврат:

```
function startTimer() {
  startTimer._timerID = window.setInterval(function() {
    setBadge(serverID);
  }, _updateTime));
}

function save_options() {
  clearInterval(startTimer._timerID);
}
```

---

вы же помните, что функции такие же объекты?